# game.h no such file or directory when using SDL with VScode

Tags: c++, sdl

So, I am learning SDL 2 and using it with vscode, this is my file structure

[image: file structure]

in the miain.cpp file this is my code:

```
#include <game.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int screenWidth = 1024;
    int screenHight = 600;
    Game game("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, screenWidth, screenHight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    while(game.gameState != GameState::EXIT){
        SDL_Event evnt;
        SDL_PollEvent(&evnt);
        switch (evnt.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                game.gameState = GameState::EXIT;
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
        }        
    };
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile I get this error:
fatal error: game.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Try ```#include <../headers/game.h>```

Comment: I'm not familiar with VSCode, but depending on whether the `headers` folder is in your include path when invoking the compiler, then the path to include should be either "headers/game.h" or even "include/headers/game.h"

Comment: no the same problem occurs

Comment: Can you post compile command that you are using?

Comment: I am just using Alt + F5 in vscode

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not VSCode but the project folding structure. You are trying to import a file using a wrong path. The correct one is `#include <../headers/game.h>`.

I suggest you to move `main.cpp` in the root project directory and `game.h` file path will be `#include <include/headers/game.h>`.

Comment: No actually the problem is still there

Comment: The problem could be in Makefile compile program, try to check

Comment: this is the MakeFile:                                                                                                      
all:
 g++ -Iinclude -Iinclude/sdl -Iinclude/headers -Llib -o Main src/*.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

Comment: Are you sure that ```game.h``` doesn't contains errors?

Comment: no it doesn't have any errors

Comment: Which importing path are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252045/discussion-between-youssef-mic-and-elnicho).